# Visual Studio Design View - form is blank

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a C# project with two forms. All compiles well. When I run the project, all forms are drawn as they are expected to.

A couple of days back, the DesignView of **all** forms started to shown nothing but a blank form, like the one you get in a new Windows.Forms project.

I went through several questions on SO with a similar problem, here are the comments to those questions:

1. there are no 3rd party libraries that my project uses (apart from htmlAgilityPack, which does not cause this problem in other Windows.Forms C# projects)
2. I have checked that the InitializeComponent function is only once in the project for each form
3. When I create a new Project and add an existing form (i.e. one of my problematic project forms), the Design Viewer works as expected - hence I suspect that the .cs, .Designer.cs and .resx files of my forms are OK.

Is there something I could have messed up in the project settings or somewhere else?

**EDIT**

The third point above is misleading - I tried creating a new project for the second form as well and there the problem persist. The minimal amount of source code that shows the problem is to to be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l410twqwzzv5kxd/mainForm.rar?dl=0).

Comment: Do you have a parameterless constructor that calls `InitializeComponent`?

Comment: @stuartd: Yes, both forms only have parameterless constructors. Each calls `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: Please post the source of one form in which no/blank designView is shown.

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz: I will be happy to but how exactly? When I move the .cs, .design.cs and .resx files to a new project, all shows all right.

Comment: Tried a new (clean) checkout from your RCS and recompile from scratch?

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz: See the edit, please.

Comment: @stuartd: I am new to C#, where would I find these project references for the form, please?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your project file has become invalid.

A valid project entry for a form looks like this:

```
<Compile Include="Form1.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Yours though is missing the DependentUpon line - which is why the code and designer files appear separately in the project, instead of being connected:

```
<Compile Include="mainForm.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="mainForm.Designer.cs" />
```

If you add in the missing line, the form displays correctly in design mode:

```
<Compile Include="mainForm.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="mainForm.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>mainForm.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

And to tidy up the resource file:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="mainForm.resx">
  <DependentUpon>mainform.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

In order to fix this, you can just edit the csproj in an editor, or to do it in Visual Studio:

1. Back up the files
2. Right-click the project and choose "Unload Project"
3. Right-click the unloaded project and choose "Edit [ProjectName].csproj"
4. Make your changes, and close the file.
5. Right-click the unloaded project and choose "Reload Project"

Comment: Thanks a lot. The source code I posted was a project made from scratch into which I have just added three source files. Do you have any idea how the project could become invalid?

Comment: That made me laugh:) Thank you much stuartd.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by removing all files associated with that form

- File -> Right-click -> Exclude from Project

and adding the files manually back to the project

- Project -> Add -> Existing Item...

Answer (score 1):

For those searching around and finding no solace, I have another solution. The project I inherited has horrible code quality and the previous developer had mixed case all over his code because "It's case insensitive, so it doesn't matter"

So, while `PopulateRevs` is, in fact, identical to `POpulateREvs` in Visual Basic, that kind of laziness leads to issues. To wit:

```
<Compile Include="Inventory\Partmaster.Designer.Vb">
  <DependentUpon>Partmaster.vb</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Inventory\Partmaster.vb">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

I happened to see this in the `.vbproj` file while looking at other solutions that didn't work. I happened to change `Partmaster.Designer.Vb` to `Partmaster.Designer.vb` (lowercase extension) and it worked.

So as another solution, while Visual Basic is not case sensitive, it looks like the `.vbproj` file is. If you're stumped, another thing to make sure is that your file names and `.proj` files share the same case.

(I realize this is tagged `C#`, but I tested this in C# and the mixed case will cause problems there as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility.  I had a group of forms all descended from a base form.  I added location save/restore code--and everything was coming up blank.

After an hour of messing with it and not being able to find anything wrong it suddenly started throwing a null reference exception in the designer rather than just being blank.  Duh--the save/restore code used an object that didn't exist design time.

Why it was silent about it and then suddenly started squawking I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: I had a super-class of Form from which all of my forms derived. I had defined this super-class in one of my form.cs files, above the (partial) class definition for the form corresponding to that file. This seems to have confused visual studio and it was displaying the contents of my super-class (i.e., an empty form) instead of the contents of the form corresponding to the file. The solution was to move the definition of the super-class to a different file that wasn't a form-designer file.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:
The designer seems to try to design the first class in the .h file, no matter what's its name.
I just had an empty forward ref class declaration before the actual form class, and it tried use that.

Answer (score 0):

If the startup Form is blank and there is no compiler error. Check if your Program.cs file is running the right Form, else it will run a Form without context and will appear blank.

In this case the Program.cs file should look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Form_Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new StartForm());
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** that Application.Run(new **StartForm**()); need to be specified correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix that worked for me:
Before the issue occurred, I changed the name of InitializeComponent() in my constructor to Initialize(). Once I changed it back to InitializeComponent() it fixed the issue and the form was visible again.